# SPList.GetItemById and Checked Out Items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, event-receivers, runwithelevatedprivileges

It seems I cannot use `SPList.GetItemById(int)` or `SPList.GetItemByUniqueId(Guid)` or `Web.GetListItem(string)` to get an item that is checked out. I have tried all three and all three result in a "File does not exist" exception.

An alternative method is to use SPQuery, which I have not tried, but have read that this too will not work.

**Question: Are there any alternatives that will work?**

*What I'm trying to achieve*
I have an `ItemAdded` event receiver. Files that are added to my document library remain checked out when they are first uploaded because I have fields that are mandatory for every file in the list that must be completed by the user before the file can be checked in.

I want to break permission inheritance on every file that is uploaded, hence the `ItemAdded` event receiver. Most users will not have permissions to set unique permissions on items, therefore have to use `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, and we know when we use this we must obtain new references to all our objects.

This is what I have at the moment; all attempts to get the list item fail:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
        {
            SPItemEventReceiverHandling rh = new SPItemEventReceiverHandling();

            try
            {                
                //Get item by ID
                //  SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
                //  SPListItem thisitem = list.GetItemById(itemId);

                //Get item by unique ID
                //  SPListItem thisitem = list.GetItemByUniqueId(itemGuid);

                //Get item by url
                //  string url = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl, item.Url);
                //  SPListItem thisitem = web.GetListItem(url);

                //Get item from event properties
                //  SPListItem thisitem = properties.ListItem;

                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                thisitem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                /* Assign unique permissions here */
                rh.DisableEventFiring();
                thisitem.Update();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                rh.EnableEventFiring();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I got around this issue by assigning temporary values to the required fields, updating the item, checking it in, then running the above piece of code with the addition of a check out before calling `thisitem.update()`, then assigning the required fields back to null.

Not ideal but it works.